# Highlighting top level link when viewing one of it's sub-pages, which are not linked in the menu

Tags: menus, pages

I have a page that is not linked in my custom menu. This page has a parent page, which is linked in the custom menu.

If I go to the "not-linked" page, I want to to highlight it's parent page link in the menu.

I use WordPress 3.0 and there is a possibility to create a custom menu (drag-and-drop - *Appearance* > *Menus*).

The custom menu uses a list for menu styling and I would like to add a class to the parent Page link within the `<li>`.
I also have pages with two, and top level parents.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress already applies the CSS class `current-page-ancestor` to the `<li>` if it is a link to a Page that is a parent (or higher) of the current Page. This follows the Page structure, not the menu structure. If this is not fit for your situation, could you edit your question to make it more clear how it differs?